# Good parsing approach after tokenization

Tags: c#, parsing, token, interpreter

I wrote a program in which I read a string or file and tokenize it. 
Example String : 
`"int w = sad&&s||a|d++ != == < > >= <= -- sadsa++ % int sads = 232.32; if reg string test = \"Hello World\";% % +- + - / * ** false true"`

Exmaple Output:

```
Token[Type:'Identifier',Value:'int',Line:'1',Position:'3']
Token[Type:'Literal',Value:'w',Line:'1',Position:'4']
Token[Type:'Assign',Value:'=',Line:'1',Position:'4']
Token[Type:'Literal',Value:'sad',Line:'1',Position:'8']
Token[Type:'Logical',Value:'&&',Line:'1',Position:'8']
Token[Type:'Literal',Value:'s',Line:'1',Position:'11']
Token[Type:'Logical',Value:'||',Line:'1',Position:'11']
Token[Type:'Literal',Value:'a',Line:'1',Position:'14']
Token[Type:'Unknown',Value:'|d',Line:'1',Position:'14']
Token[Type:'Literal',Value:'d',Line:'1',Position:'16']
Token[Type:'Arithmetic',Value:'++',Line:'1',Position:'16']
Token[Type:'Relational',Value:'!=',Line:'1',Position:'18']
Token[Type:'Relational',Value:'==',Line:'1',Position:'20']
Token[Type:'Relational',Value:'<',Line:'1',Position:'22']
Token[Type:'Relational',Value:'>',Line:'1',Position:'23']
Token[Type:'Relational',Value:'>=',Line:'1',Position:'24']
Token[Type:'Relational',Value:'<=',Line:'1',Position:'26']
Token[Type:'Arithmetic',Value:'--',Line:'1',Position:'28']
Token[Type:'Literal',Value:'sadsa',Line:'1',Position:'35']
Token[Type:'Arithmetic',Value:'++',Line:'1',Position:'35']
Token[Type:'Arithmetic',Value:'%',Line:'1',Position:'37']
Token[Type:'Identifier',Value:'int',Line:'1',Position:'41']
Token[Type:'Literal',Value:'sads',Line:'1',Position:'45']
Token[Type:'Assign',Value:'=',Line:'1',Position:'45']
Token[Type:'DoubleValue',Value:'232.32',Line:'1',Position:'51']
Token[Type:'Semicolon',Value:';',Line:'1',Position:'51']
Token[Type:'Identifier',Value:'if',Line:'1',Position:'53']
Token[Type:'Literal',Value:'reg',Line:'1',Position:'56']
Token[Type:'Identifier',Value:'string',Line:'1',Position:'62']
Token[Type:'Literal',Value:'test',Line:'1',Position:'66']
Token[Type:'Assign',Value:'=',Line:'1',Position:'66']
Token[Type:'StringValue',Value:'Hello World',Line:'1',Position:'78']
Token[Type:'Semicolon',Value:';',Line:'1',Position:'78']
Token[Type:'Arithmetic',Value:'%',Line:'1',Position:'78']
Token[Type:'Arithmetic',Value:'%',Line:'1',Position:'79']
Token[Type:'Unknown',Value:'+-',Line:'1',Position:'80']
Token[Type:'Arithmetic',Value:'+',Line:'1',Position:'82']
Token[Type:'Arithmetic',Value:'-',Line:'1',Position:'83']
Token[Type:'Arithmetic',Value:'/',Line:'1',Position:'84']
Token[Type:'Arithmetic',Value:'*',Line:'1',Position:'85']
Token[Type:'Unknown',Value:'**',Line:'1',Position:'86']
Token[Type:'Identifier',Value:'false',Line:'1',Position:'93']
Token[Type:'Identifier',Value:'true',Line:'1',Position:'97']
Elapsed time: 31
```

(Ignore Position, has to be fixed in the future)

So now I do not really know a good approach to further interpret this in order to run a simple little scripting language on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good first approach is to come up with names for each thing, like "operation", "operand", "literal", "declaration" etc.

Then make a function that can read each of those from your token stream, and calls the others where appropriate. E.g. If you have:

```
operation: <operand> <operator> <operand>
operator: + | -
operand: <number> | <string>
```

etc., then you can have a function (pseudocode):

```
Operation parseOperation( tokens )
{
    Operand operand1 = parseOperand( tokens )
    Operation theOp = new Operation( tokens.fetchNextToken() )
    Operand operand2 = parseOperand( tokens )
    theOp.operand[0] = operand1
    theOp.operand[1] = operand2
    return theOp
}
```

and implement the other functions in a similar way. Of course, some functions may have to examine the next token to decide which other function to call, or even look ahead several tokens.

This is usually called a "recursive descent" parser.

Each of the functions returns an object that represents an operation and has its arguments hanging off of it. This is basically a tree structure, which you can then recursively walk ("depth-first").

The easiest way is to give the different object types you define dor your operations and values methods like asString() or asInt() and then do things like:

```
int Operation::asInt()
{
   int a = operand[0].asInt()
   int b = operand[1].asInt()
   return a + b;
}
```

Objects that are already the right type (like an IntOperand class) would just return their value:

```
int IntOperand::asInt()
{
    return self.numericValue
}
```

or whatever. Objects that aren't the right type either produce an error instead of returning a value, or convert themselves. So no matter how complex the expression, in the end you get an int or string or whatever out.

To run a program, you can now ask the bottom-most object for its value.